# Error displaying Tab ios

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I'm trying to create an app with two tabs. When I get to the scene where I can choose between tabs, the first one (the one which is loaded automatically) is showing as desired. But, when I click the second tab, it goes behind the Navigation Bar. Both Controllers have the same configuration, as far as I know. I can't find the problem here. 
If I swap the order of the tabs the issue is the same. It looks like that the problem is with the Tab Bar Controller.
What can I do to fix it? Thanks.

[image: Frist Tab]
[image: Second Tab]
[image: How the second tab should be shown]

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

on your -ViewDidLoad Method of the 2nd view